# Using Partitioner with PLINQ in F#

Tags: f#, partitioning, plinq

I use the following PLINQ-implemented parallel map function.

```
let parmap f (xs:list<_>) = xs.AsParallel().Select(fun x -> f x) |> Seq.toList
```

I want to improve my speedup on 4 cores which I'm not able to get above 2. I found one can do custom partitioning to improve the parallel performance. But I have seen C# examples mainly and not sure how to get it to work with F#. The following doesn't change anything but then I think it is the default partitioning used by TPL? How can I use the different (static, dynamic,...) partitioning options here?

```
let pmap_plinqlst_parts f (xs:list<_>) = 
    let parts = Partitioner.Create(xs)
    parts.AsParallel().Select(fun x -> f x) |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: You should first find out why is the speedup limited and not make wild guesses as to what would fix it. The default partitioner should be good enough in most cases. I don't think a custom one will help you, unless you have quite a special case.

Comment: What are you trying to parallelize? There is no universal solution for all parallelism problems. In general, `Parallel.For(Each)` is more compelling and easier to customize (using `Partitioner`) than `PLINQ`.

Comment: I am playing around with different parallel map implementations to solve problems (e.g. mandelbrot) that exhibit data parallelism in a function style. So doing the same work for each element of a big list in parallel, but the independent work can be of varying size. I tried Async Workflows, PLINQ and also Par For. While all gives initial parallelism, they do not scale beyond 2 cores.

Comment: @vis: It's strange since Mandelbrot is an *embarrassingly parallel* problem. Implementation details matter here. Could you post a complete example?

Answer (score 1):

Typically a custom partitioner would be used if the work units were extremely small.  When faced with this problem you may be better off switching to Task rather than Async as its generally more suited to smaller but more numerous amounts of work, with Async being more suited to IO type operations where the latency would be typically longer.

For example you would batch up calculations in sequences amongst parallel threads.  The yield would vary depending on the size of the work units and also the number of total items.

There is no limit to scaling in any of the methods you mentioned.  I parallelised  a Black Scholes calculation and managed to get around 6.8x on an 8 core machine using Async.Parallel.  Although not a perfect mechanism I used a simple division of work amongst the initial sequences that were passed to Async.Parallel.

Are you sure you have a true four core machine or a two core machine with hyper threading?